# creating component in onPress event

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build an android app using functional react-native and expo.
I want to know to create new components inside other components when events are triggered.
What I'm trying to do is the following
The code I wrote is below:

```
<View>
   <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.container} onPress = {() => {return (
             <TouchabeOpacity>
                 <Text> Hello World </Text>
             </TouchabeOpacity> ) }}
    </ToucchabeOpacity>

</View>
```

I want when pressing the first touchableopacity another one would be created and displayed.
Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
import {NewComponent} from './components/NewComponent';

....

const[displayNewComponent, setDisplayNewComponent] = useState(false)

...

<View>
   <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.container} onPress={() => setDisplayNewComponent(true)}
    { displayNewComponent && <NewComponent /> }
    </ToucchabeOpacity>

</View>
```

```
export const NewComponent = () => {
       return (
             <TouchabeOpacity>
                 <Text> Hello World </Text>
             </TouchabeOpacity> 
       )
```